# Deciphering File::Fetch error

Tags: perl, download, fetch

I was trying to use File::Fetch in a simple script to download a file. Unfortunately, it errors out and I can't seem to find why.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Fetch;
my $url = 'https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/42.0b7/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-42.0b7.tar.bz2';
my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => $url);
my $where = $ff->fetch( to => '/tmp' ) or die $ff->error;
print "Downloaded to ".$where."\n";
```

At execution:

```
#./filefetch.pl
Use of uninitialized value in die at ./filefetch.pl line 12.
Died at ./filefetch.pl line 12.
```

Comment: This particular url seem to work with http as well as https. That may be used as work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going into `File::Fetch::fetch()` with the debugger, the problem is File::Fetch failed to find a way to deal with the `https` scheme. It appears to have [no support for `https`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Fetch#HOW-IT-WORKS). It correctly returned false, but it did not populate its error field.

You are correct in assuming it should consider missing a scheme an error. You can [report a bug here](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=File-Fetch).